# RazorViewsForMarketers is not working in sitecore MVC

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-mvc

i'm using web form for marketers in sitecore MVC using RazorViewsForMarketers, i following              this https://github.com/PetersonDave/RazorViewsForMarketers/

1. I have successfully installed module: Razor-Views-For-Marketers-Rendering.zip
2. i have copied RazorViewsForMarketers.config in my project

now issue with adding a reference to RazorViewsForMarketers, i'm not getting how to find this .dll please anyone help me to figure out this issue

anyone who did work on web form form marketers in Sitecore MVC, please suggest me how to use it in Sitecore MVC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dll is not in the package, the package only includes items related to this module.

You need to Build the [this project](https://github.com/PetersonDave/RazorViewsForMarketers/tree/master/Source/RazorViewsForMarketers) locally and get the dll from it.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, i added reference for RazorViewsForMarketers & install package in my sitecore successfully for this after this i got folder named as "Razor Views"  it contains Razor Views For Marketers Rendering item but when i'm opening this it gives an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Could you update your question with full error stack?

Comment: Did you copy all files in /Views/* to website root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68075/discussion-between-amitavin-and-ahmed-okour).